# Variable in function needs to be in single quotes

Tags: vb.net

I am using `DataTable.Select()` in VB.Net and the in the argument I need single quotes. For example:

`DataTable.Select("column = 'value'")`
But I want value to be a variable.

I have tried:

`DataTable.Select("column = " + var )` Produces error column [var] not found

`DataTable.Select("column = '" + var + "'")` Produces IndexOutOfBoundsException

`DataTable.Select("column = 'actual value'")`  Works

When using the actual value the variable holds instead of the variable it works so it must be something with the single quotes and concatenation of the variable.

Comment: The string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`. However, `DataSet.Select($"column = '{var}'")` might be easier to use: [Interpolated Strings (Visual Basic Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings).

Comment: `DataSet.Select`? Where does this method come from? `DataTable` has a `Select` method, but not `DataSet`. Example: `dataSet.Tables(0).Select(s)`. Did you name your `DataTable` variable `DataSet`?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I meant DataTable.Select(). Will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no DataSet.Select method. There is a DataTable.Select method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select)). I'm going to assume that you are referring to it in my answer.

---

Your 2nd example should work. If it is not then you will need to setup a breakpoint, inspect the value being passed to the Select method, and verify that it matches up with what you are expecting.

I would make one change and that is to use String interpolation or String.Format. This helps the code's readability.

This is a working example:

```vb
' create/seed the table
Dim table = New DataTable("Table1")
Dim column = New DataColumn("Column1")
table.Columns.Add(column)
For index = 1 To 10
    table.Rows.Add({"Cell" & index.ToString()})
Next

' get value
Dim value = "Cell1"
Dim hardcodedValue = table.Select("Column1 = 'Cell1'")
Console.WriteLine(hardcodedValue(0)(0))
Dim variableValue = table.Select(String.Format("Column1 = '{0}'", value))
Console.WriteLine(variableValue(0)(0))
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7kZpY5

Comment: Thank you. Yes I meant DataTable.Select()